# Google Cloud Big Query Table Missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google, google-app-engine

I have Created a Table under a Dataset. But When Some weeks When I tried to Access the Table. I came to know that It is missing. I go to LOGGING EXPLORER For Check the Table Related Activities. But In The Logging explorer it is also nothing. Can Anyone Guide What Can be the Reason Behind this thing?